# How to clean up the resources,connection,hanging after Thread.interrupt?

Tags: java

Could some explains me how to cleanup the resources after executing thread.interrupt?

a. I/O hanged for a long time during reading/writing a file
b. DB query takes more time when query is executed via hibernate
c. Called a Third Party API and the response is not being received for a long time.
d. Any other resources should be cleaned.

Thanks,
Kathir

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a use for a `try`/`catch`/`finally` block. Record your handles etc. and close in the `finally` block. Watch out that your handle references aren't null if that's a possibility. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) for more info. Note that this isn't specific to clearing up after interrupts. You should handle resource cleanup properly in all scenarios.

If you're using Java 7 check out the [try-with-resources construction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which is a more concise form of the above.

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one
>   or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after
>   the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement
>   ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any
>   object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all
>   objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.

Comment: Yup.  Just like you should tidy up even if you weren't designing to support interrupts.

Comment: could you please provide an example of code snippet for each of the above as the answer is not clear?